# How to format Date in inputText

Tags: angular, date, format, primeng

I'm using primeng, how can i display a date in input with another format (dd/MM/yyyy) :

```
<label class="col-form-label" >Date</label>
<input type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="object.dateCreation" [readonly]="true" >

object: Object = {
    dateCreation: new Date();
}
```

Below how the date is diplayed :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

For displaying in HTML ::

`{{dateCreation | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

For sending data to backend, Inject its dependency such as

```
providers :[DatePipe]

constructor(private datePipe:DatePipe) {}
```

and now, transform the date using the method available :

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.dateCreation, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 2):

you should apply pipe this way:

```
<input type="text" size="30" pInputText [ngModel]="object.dateCreation | date : 'medium" (ngModelChange)="object.dateCreation = $event" [readonly]="true">
```